# Is the unique asset deck reshuffled when cards are discarded?

Tags: eldritch-horror

It is quite clear from the base game rules that normal **asset cards** are put in a separate discard pile when they are discarded, whereas **condition cards** and **spell cards** are shuffled back into the deck when discarded.

Mountains of Madness expansion introduces a new deck of **unique asset cards**, which have similarities both to normal assets and to conditions/spells. What happens when **unique asset cards** when they are discarded? Are they put into a separate discard pile, or reshuffled back into the deck?

Answer (score 3):

The unique asset cards are still asset cards therefore they are discarded and not shuffled back in.

As [Joey](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/12617/joey) stated in a comment:

> Considering the reason they (the assert cards) are shuffled right back
>   in is likely to retain the variety of these "double-sided same on one
>   side different on the other" cards, the unique assets are likely
>   handled like assets and artefacts.

Also, the unique assets are unique. Which means that, from a story telling point of view, you cannot get the same one twice within a game. It would make no logical sense.

Comment: Considering the reason they are shuffled right back in is likely to retain the variety of these "double-sided same on one side different on the other" cards, the unique assets are likely handled like assets and artifacts.

Comment: @Joey, your comment if expended a little would make a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, you pretty much answered the yes or no part. I just thought I'd add some thoughts in addition. You're welcome to integrate it into your answer of course.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect. The rulebook for Mountains of Madness states: "Like Spells or Conditions, Unique Assets are double-sided cards". Also in the FAQ section it says: "Q. Can an investigator have multiple copies of the same Unique Asset?
A. Yes. There is no limit to the number of Unique Assets an investigator can have.". So you CAN get the same one twice within a game

Answer (score 1):

> Double-sided cards, such as Spells or Conditions, are immediately
>   shuffled back into their respective decks when discarded.

Source: [Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf), "Discarding" (page 5)

Unique Assets are double-sided cards.

The Mountains of Madness (or later) rules don't list any exception that would make you not shuffle them when discarded.

You shuffle them in, just like all other double-sided cards.